# In php, should I return false, null, or an empty array in a method that would usually return an array?

Tags: php, methods, return-value

I've found several responses to this, but none pertaining to PHP (which is an extremely weak typed language):

With regards to *PHP*, is it appropriate to return false, null, or an empty array in a method that would usually return an array, but has a failure occur?

In other words, if another developer jumped in on my project, what would they expect to see?

Comment: I'd say - return an empty array.

Comment: If you're not working with exceptions, I'd say don't return an empty array in case of an error. Even more if an empty array could be a correct result.

Comment: Return an empty array. If it normally returns an array then returning an array won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

An array is a collection of things. An empty array would signal that *"everything went fine, there just isn't anything in that collection"*. If you actually want to signal an **error**, you should return `false`. Since PHP is dynamically typed, it's easy to check the return value either strictly or loosely, depending on what you need:

```
$result = getCollection();

if (!$result)           // $result was false or empty, either way nothing useful
if ($result === false)  // an actual error occurred
if ($result)            // we have an array with content
```

There are also *exceptions* for error reporting in *exceptional* cases. It really depends on the responsibilities of the function and the severity of errors. If the role of the function allows the response "empty collection" and "nope" equally, the above may be fine. However, if the function by definition must always return a collection (even if that's empty) and in certain circumstances it cannot, throwing an exception may be a lot more appropriate than returning `false`.

Comment: Great answer. Do you know why they are using false instead of null?

Comment: Who is "they"? And `null` means "no value", a function returning `null` doesn't really return any value. `false` is "bad", "fail", "wrong", "negative".

Comment: "they" is PHP built-in functions.

Comment: Returning false only says "Something went wrong".  Returning an error code means you need to handle them.  If you need to be more specific then exceptions are probably a better option.

Comment: IMO, returning `false` is strange and may lead to incorrect assumptions. Imagine method `isRegistered(Client $client)` returning `bool`. If this method returns `false` you cannot be sure if there was actually an error or client is not yet registered. I think it's much clearer to `throw` an `Exception` and let the caller to choose what do at the higher levels when they got broader context.  
Returning `false` at the bottom level you are making decisions for the caller how his code should behave.

Comment: @WhiteAngel Yes, but the question was about returning an array, not a bool, so the ambiguity you suggest wouldn't occur.  It's also not necessarily an exception.  Let's say you have a web service that returns an array of orders for a customer, which calls a function that queries the database and returns the dataset.  if there are no orders for the customer, you return an empty array from the db function, then you return a code 204 to the client.  If the customer doesn't exist you return false from the db function then return a 404 to the client becasue that resource doesn't exist.

Comment: @CraigJacobs, I don't agree with you. Your coding style should be constant no matter if the return type is `bool` or `array`. You tried to show an example where you said that `false !== error` (when user doesn't exist) but at the same time you are returning error code to the user (404 is an error code). From my point of view, if someone requested user orders and user doesn't exist it's absolutely legitimate for DOJO function to throw an exception that user doesn't exist and API Dispatcher will chose what to do with this exception: return response, try different name, return default value, ...

Comment: @GordonM interestingly the cakephp querybuilder function `fetch()` returns an `array` if it has "fetched" values but if there was no value which is totally normal in a database if you make a specific select it returns `false`.
The phpdoc says: "@return array|false Result array containing columns and values or false if no results are left"

Comment: @SamuelGfeller The problem with that kind of approach is you then have to write a lot more boilerplate code such as ```if (is_array ($result)) { foreach ($result as $record) { /*...*/ }}``` whereas if you always return an array whether you got results back or not then the foreach doesn't need to be guarded (foreaching an empty array is effectively a no-op).  Generally I favor an approach of always return what you promise to return unless it's impossible in which case throw an appropriately typed exception.

Comment: @GordonM sure and I totally agree with you on that. I implemented it as such in my code too but noticed that behavior on the cakephp/database `fetch` function and thought it was surprising and interesting to mention

Comment: @SamuelGfeller People have an unfortunate tendency to hold up what developers do in frameworks as examples of best practice, when the people who develop frameworks are just developers just like any other.  Some are better than others, some do things they shouldn't, and a framework's code quality is not guaranteed to be any better than any other code just because it's in a framework.  If you disagree with something a framework is doing (and in this case I disagree strongly) you're under no obligation to follow its conventions.

Answer (score 15):

I would strongly discourage to return mixed type return values. I consider it to be so much a problem, that i wrote a small article about [not returning mixed typed values](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#mixedReturnType).

To answer your question, return an empty array. Below you can find a small example, why returning other values can cause problems:

```
// This kind of mixed-typed return value (boolean or string),
// can lead to unreliable code!
function precariousCheckEmail($input)
{
  if (filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    return true;
  else
    return 'E-Mail address is invalid.';
}

// All this checks will wrongly accept the email as valid!
$result = precariousCheckEmail('nonsense');
if ($result == true)
  print('OK'); // -> OK will be given out

if ($result)
  print('OK'); // -> OK will be given out

if ($result === false)
  print($result);
else
  print('OK'); // -> OK will be given out

if ($result == false)
  print($result);
else
  print('OK'); // -> OK will be given out
```

Hope this helps preventing some misunderstandings.

Comment: Passing the additional parameter by reference is a nice solution to handling possible errors.

Comment: You have mislead yourself in your answer because you are using true as the return.  The return value will always be true. You need to return false on failure or a proper value on success.  That paradigm is what works in PHP.

Comment: @Jeff - That's exactly what I meant, without knowing the code inside `precariousCheckEmail()` your are never sure how the return value must be checked. Please try it out, the example will return `OK` four times, in the linked article you can find more information about it. It is not uncommon to return `true` in case of success and an error message otherwise.

Comment: Even when returning false instead of true, there is the pitfall of using `($result == false)` instead of `($result === false)`, I have seen this a lot. But I wanted to point out the problem in a more general way, in my opinion avoiding mixed typed return values leads to better readability and more stable code.

Comment: Another problem with the above approach is it mixes logic and presentation.  What if you need to display an error message in French?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a modern answer that's been valid since the 1960's probably.

Some bad design choices in the earliest versions of PHP (before PHP 4) have made many PHP developers exposed to conventions that have always been bad. Fortunately, PHP 5 have come and gone - which helped guide many PHP developers on to the "right path".

PHP 7 is now seeing the benefits of having been through the PHP 5 phase - it is one of the fastest performing script languages in existence.

- and this has made it possible to make PHP 7 one of the fastest and most powerful scripting languages in existence.

Since PHP version 4, huge efforts have been made by PHP core developers to gradually improve the PHP language. Many things remain, because we still want to have *some* backward compatability.

**DON'T return *false* on error**

> *The only time you can return FALSE in case of error, is if your function is named something like `isEverythingFine()`.*

`false` has always been the wrong value to return for errors. The reason you still see it in PHP documentation, is because of backward compatability.

1. It would be inconsistent. What do you return on error in those cases where your function is supposed to return a boolean `true` or `false`?
2. If your function is supposed to return something other than booleans, then you force yourself to write code to handle type checking. Since many people don't do type checking, the PHP opcode compiler is also forced to write opcodes that does type checking as well. *You get double type checking!*

**You *may* return null**

Most scripting languages have made efficient provisions for the `null` value in their data types. Ideally, you don't even use that value type - but if you can't throw an exception, then I would prefer `null`. It is a valid "value" for all data types in PHP - even if it is not a valid value internally in the PC.

Optimally for the computer/CPU is that the entire value is located in a single 1, 2, 4 or 8 byte memory "cell". These value sizes are common for all native value types.

When values are allowed to be `null`, then this must be encoded in a separate memory cell and whenever the computer needs to pass values to a function or return them, it must return two values. One containing `isNull` and another for the value.

**You *may* return a special value depending on type**

This is not ideal, because

- If your function is supposed to return an integer, then return -1.
- If your function is supposed to return a string

**You *should* throw exceptions**

Exceptions match the inner workings of most CPUs. They have a dedicated internal flag to declare that an exceptional event occurred.

It is highly efficient, and even if it wasn't we have gigantic benefits of not having a lot of extra work in the normal non-erroneous situation.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your assertion that null 'is a valid "value" for all data types in PHP', but if I write a function and declare the return type as `int`, for example, and then return `null` then PHP throws a TypeError. So, `null` is _not_ a valid value for other data types. If I want the possibility of returning `null` in some circumstances than I need to declare the return type as `?int` to show that both data types can be returned.

Comment: @WebSmithery There is no way to say that the return type is either int or false. But there is a way to say int or null, as you point out. If you declare a typed property on a class in PHP, it can have the value null. I don't see where you want to go with this. Null is not a data type. It is "nothing" ?int means either you get an integer, or you get nothing. No chance you'll get a string or a bool. In any case; "both data types" is not the words I would use.

Answer (score 5):

Just speaking for myself, I normally prefer to return an empty array, because if the function always returns an array, it's safe to use it with PHP's array functions and foreach (they'll accept empty arrays).  If you return null or false, then you'll have to check the type of the result before passing it to an array function.

If you need to distinguish between the case where the method executed correctly but didn't find any results, and the case where an error occurred in the method, then that's where exceptions come in.  In the former case it's safe to return an empty array.  In the latter simply returning an empty array is insufficient to notify you of the fact an error occurred.  However if you return something other than an array then you'll have to deal with that in the calling code.  Throwing an exception lets you handle errors elsewhere in an appropriate error handler and lets you attach a message and a code to the exception to describe why the failure happened.

The below pseudo-code will simply return an empty array if we don't find anything of interest.  However, if something goes wrong when processing the list of things we got back then an exception is thrown.

```
method getThings () {
    $things = array ();
    if (get_things_we_are_interested_in ()) {
        $things [] = something_else ();
    } 
    if (!empty ($things)) {
        if (!process_things ($things)) {
            throw new RuntimeExcpetion ('Things went wrong when I tried to process your things for the things!');
        }
    }
    return $things;
}
```

Comment: How can you distinguish an error occurred in the method? For logging and error handling we need to check it.

Comment: If some failure occurs then you'd probably want to throw an exception.  Then you can distinguish between no error occurring and no results being found, and an error occurring.  In the event of no error and no results you get an empty array, in the event of an error you get an exception

Comment: Good thought. You should Add this to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the situation and how bad the error is, but a good (and often overlooked) option is to [throw an exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php):

```
<?php
function inverse($x) {
    if (!$x) {
        throw new Exception('Division by zero.');
    }
    else return 1/$x;
}

try {
    echo inverse(5) . "\n";
    echo inverse(0) . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

This will ensure that your function will not fail silently and errors won't go unseen.

Comment: You should reserve exceptions for exceptional circumstances (the clue's in the name).  $x not having a non-empty value isn't exceptional.  Exceptions can lead to convoluted flow control (they're effectively a kind of goto), and in PHP they're expensive compared to if/else

Comment: @GordonM that is the PHP documentations example

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the return type of your method is array, so you should return an empty array only if the execution went fine but no results were found.

In case of an error, you should throw an exception. This should be the preferred way to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever you prefer, though I suggest an empty array for the for a good reason. You don't have to check the type first!

```
<?php
function return_empty_array() {
    return array();
}

$array = return_empty_array();

// there are no values, thus code within doesn't get executed
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ' => ' . $value . PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

In any other case, if you'd return false or null, you'd get an error at the foreach loop.

It's a minuscule difference, though in my opinion a big one. I don't want to check what type of value I got, I want to assume it's an array. If there are no results, then it's an empty array.

Anyway, as far as I'm concerned there are no "defaults" for returning empty values. Native PHP functions keep amazing me with the very different values it returns. Sometimes false, sometimes null, sometimes an empty object.

Comment: I recall foreach being annoying function and making an error if the array provided is empty :/

Comment: That's not been my experience.  When I've used foreach on an empty array it's just skipped over the code contained in the foreach and not executed it.

Comment: @GordonM I hope you're kidding... The foreach loop runs that code for every element in the array. If the array is empty... well... no code gets executed... obviously.

Comment: ah I now understand. The problem is I was quite lazy when it comes to initializing variables. I think this example will explain what I meant :) http://codepad.org/tuN9ic39 From now, all my arrays will get initialized.

Answer (score 0):

If there's really a problem then you should raise an error, otherwise if the criteria aren't met etc then return a blank array.